# Ride-share or alternate means of getting from Dunedin to Queenstown?

Tags: transportation, new-zealand, queenstown

I have my second Dunedin-Queenstown trip coming up this weekend, but due to some student holidays, no car-rentals are available.

Flight is booked, so scrambling to find an alternative to get from Dunedin to Queenstown late on the Friday night or early Saturday morning.

Does NZ have any ride-sharing sites or online forums which may be of assistance?

Comment: What's wrong with [taking the bus, as suggested by rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Dunedin/Queenstown)?

Comment: *"Does NZ have any ride-sharing sites or online forums which may be of assistance?"* - What have you looked at so far? A quick Google search already yields a whole bunch of ride-sharing/carpooling related websites.

Comment: All abandonware, or very low routes. The problem with the bus, AFAIK, is that it runs from midday, where my question specified late Friday night/Saturday morning. I'm exploring other rental agencies and even a motorbike renter.

Answer (score 4):

The solution on short notice was to change Google search criteria to something along the lines of "private car hire Dunedin", which resulted in a chauffeur service which also rented their executive cars. With full insurance, it resulted in about 4 times the price of a cheap rental agency, but was a very safe and well handling car.

Answer (score 4):

As you noted the bus times aren't ideal, [InterCity](http://www.intercity.co.nz/) has a bus that leaves daily in the afternoon, as does [Alpine Connexions](http://alpineconnexions.co.nz/scheduled-service/wanaka-queenstown-dunedin/).

It looks like [Atomic Travel](http://www.atomictravel.co.nz/) does have a morning, albeit not early morning, bus: 10:00 Dunedin - (via Cromwell) - Wanaka 14:30.